# Unity and VR for complex construction CAD models

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, cad, revit

I work in construction and we are trying to visualize our projects using Unity and Oculus Rift.

Basically all our models are created using Revit and we export them out to fbx and bring them into Unity. For each model we have (electrical, mechanical, architectural, facade...) we generate a fbx in Revit and bring into Unity.

The models have around 3000 to 60000 objects(meshes) and around 3 million to 40 million polygons. When we try to visualize the models in Unity we are getting very low FPS, around 2 to 3 fps, and batch draw calls around 15000 to 20000.

I believe the problem is the complexity of all our models that we bring together into Unity. I wonder if there is any way to optimize it, I already tried decimating, disabling shadows, occlusion but nothing seems to work. Collapsing the models into a single object is not an option because we have to allow the user to select and inspect individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on something similar and i can share some experiences for tasks like this with many vertices or meshes. I am trying to visualize point clouds in Unity and it is a very challenging task. In my case though i create point clouds myself and i do not triangulate them. It helps but i still have to apply optimizations.

From my experience if you have vertices more than 10 million rendered at a frame you start to have fps issues. This can vary based on your hardware of course. Also i am sure this will be even worse with triangulated meshes. What i have done to optimize things are following:

1. I first started by rendering objects that are in [Camera Frustum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html) In order to do this i used a function called `IsVisibleFrom` which is an [extension](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=IsVisibleFrom) to `Renderer` like this:

   using UnityEngine;

   ```
   public static class RendererExtensions
   {
         public static bool IsVisibleFrom(this Renderer renderer, Camera camera)
         {
               Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
               return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, renderer.bounds);
         }
   }
   ```

Then you can use it like this by traversing all the meshes you have:

```
Renderer grid;
IEnumerator RenderVisibleGameObject()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < PointCloud.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        grid = PointCloud.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Renderer>();
        if (!grid.IsVisibleFrom(cam))
        {
            grid.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            grid.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }


        if (i == (PointCloud.transform.childCount - 1))
            yield return null;

    }

    StartCoroutine(RenderVisibleGameObject());
}
```

2. Second option would be if possible and if you can create meshes with lower detail using [Level of Detail](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LevelOfDetail.html). Basically what it does is rendering low detail meshes that are further away from camera.
3. Last option i can recommend is using [Occlusion Culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html). This is similar to first option but it also takes care of occlusions which was not the case for me because i had only points.

Answer (score 2):

You may also find the Forge Unity AR/VR toolkit of interest:

- [Overview](https://forgetoolkit.com)
- [Introduction](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/introducing-forge-arvr-toolkit)
- [23-minute video](https://youtu.be/I5RBVA1Kipk)

As you probably know, Forge is highly optimised for professional visualisation of large CAD models.